# how printf handle character strings

Tags: c, string, pointers

look at the code below

```
char *p="bayant";  // char pointer
char str[ ] = "bayant"; // char array
printf("%s",p);//here we are passing pointer
printf("%s",str);//here we are passing strings base address
```

But how it works as we are using same format for a pointer and string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%s` conversion specification requires a `char *` argument.

In the second case you have an array of `char` argument, but C rules convert (except in a few cases) an expression of type array of `char` to type `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

An array in C is implicitly a pointer to the type. So str is essentially a pointer to a char too.

When you do c="string" C creates the string in the memory and c is a pointer to the first char in it.

When you do char str [] = "string" C creates the same string in the memory and str is a pointer to the first char in it.

Answer (score 1):

For all it matters to `printf`, **p** and **str** are the same type of thing for printf.

Both are simply a pointer to an array of characters. So printf looks to where they point and uses the charaters, up to the next `\0`.

Answer (score 1):

In the both cases `p` & `str` are the address holding the strings, with the format specifier `%s` used to print it.

Here is a typical memory layout for your assumption,

```
     +------+ 
p--->|bayant|
     +------+
```

and

```
   +------+   
str|bayant|
   +------+
```

Answer (score 0):

the first one is a pointer and the second one is array. So any function can differenciate between these two overloads:

```
void foo(char* p){}
void foo(char str[]){}
```

If you intended to ask this. Otherwise an arrayname and pointer are really same in c